# Apollo server + React Apollo pubSub not showing data

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, react-apollo

After a mutation I can't seem to receive the pubSub data on my react front end

I have the following Graphql schema:

```
type SSiD {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    status: String
    hidden: Boolean
 }
type Subscription {
  SSiDAdded: SSiD
}
```

On my apolloServer after the mudation I send the pubSub data like this

```
const data = result.dataValues
data.__typename = 'SSiD'
console.log(data)
context.pubsub.publish('SSiDAdded', data)
```

That console.log will output:

```
{ id: 2208,
  name: 'FooBar',
  hidden: true,
  status: 'broadcasting',
  updatedAt: 2016-10-27T22:07:09.119Z,
  createdAt: 2016-10-27T22:07:09.119Z,
  __typename: 'SSiD' }
```

And finally on my react front end I have the following:

```
const query = gql`
  subscription ssidList{
    SSiDAdded{
      id
      name
      hidden
    }
  }
`
this.subscriptionObserver = this.props.client.subscribe({
  query
})
.subscribe({
  next (data) {
    console.log('The subscription data', data)
  },
  error (err) {
    console.error('Error subscription', err)
  }
})
```

}

On the console.log above subscription data is always null.

Am I wrapping the response wrong or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a couple things to check. On my schema, it has some syntax I'm not seeing in yours at the moment. See the `: instant_message` after the query strings?

```
const typeDefinitions = [`

type instant_message {
  id: Int
  fromID: String
  toID: String
  msgText: String
}
type Query {
  instant_message(id: Int, fromID: String, toID: String, msgText: String): [instant_message]
}
type Mutation {
  createIM(
    fromID: String!
    toID: String!
    msgText: String!
  ): instant_message
}
type Subscription {
  # Subscription fires on every comment added
  IMAdded(id: Int, fromID: String!, toID: String!): instant_message
}

schema {
  query: Query,
  mutation: Mutation
  subscription: Subscription
}

`];
```

I've got some different syntax on the client as well:

```
subscribe(fromID, toID, updateQueryViaSubscription) {
    const SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY = gql`
      subscription getIMsViaSubscription($fromID: String!, $toID: String!){
          IMAdded(fromID:$fromID, toID: $toID){
            id,
            fromID,
            toID,
            msgText
          }
        } 
`;
    this.subscriptionObserver = this.props.client.subscribe({
        query: SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
        variables: { fromID: this.fromID, toID: this.toID },
    }).subscribe({
        next(data) {
            const newMsag = data.IMAdded;
            updateQueryViaSubscription((previousResult) => {
                // if it's our own mutation, we might get the subscription result
                // after the mutation result.
                // if (isDuplicateIM(newComment, previousResult.entry.comments)) {
                //     return previousResult;
                // }
                // update returns a new "immutable" list with the new comment
                // added to the front.
                return update(
                    previousResult,
                    {
                        instant_message: {
                            $push: [newMsag],
                        },
                    }
                );
            });
        },
        error(err) {
            console.error('err', err); },
    });
}
```

Please check that and let me know if the updated code gets rid of that error yet.

**UPDATE:** Per our discussion on Slack, you found that you needed your executableSchema to be like this:

```
const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: typeDefinitions,
    resolvers: Resolvers,
    connectors: Connectors,
    logger: console,
});

export default executableSchema;
```

Here's the resolver I'm using:

```
Subscription: {
    IMAdded(IMThatWasAdded) {
        var ret = IMThatWasAdded;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the backend I'm using the ":" it's :SSiD is just that I ain't taking any parameters so it just becomes name: ReturnType, on the front end I think is somewhat similar "queryName{subscriptionName{fields}}"